# Nothing happens when I tried to run liferay 6.1.1. on a existing Tomcat 7 server

Tags: liferay, tomcat7, liferay-6

Any help will be welcome.

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen11-installing-liferay-on-tomcat-7-0) steps, trying to run liferay 6.1.1. on a existing tomcat, but nothing happens when I launch tomcat server.

Server's log message (see), seems to be normal, but every tomcat default app is loaded, except liferay's war file. When I hit localhost:8080/, all I receive is a nice 404 status!

**//Tomcat logs**:

```
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:22 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /Users/cbs_sp/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:23 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1991 ms
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:23 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.32
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:23 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /Cesar/Profissional/Projetos/Meu/Java/Liferay/Server/liferay_home/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/conf/Catalina/localhost/ROOT.xml
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Cesar/Profissional/Projetos/Meu/Java/Liferay/Server/liferay_home/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/docs
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:26 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Cesar/Profissional/Projetos/Meu/Java/Liferay/Server/liferay_home/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/examples
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Cesar/Profissional/Projetos/Meu/Java/Liferay/Server/liferay_home/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/host-manager
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /Cesar/Profissional/Projetos/Meu/Java/Liferay/Server/liferay_home/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/webapps/manager
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Nov 14, 2012 3:10:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4691 ms
```

Any idea about what might be happening?
Or, where I can start?

Thanks in advance,

*** Additional info added ****

**//Terminal**:

```
[Cesars-Computer: apache-tomcat-7.0.32] $ cd webapps/
[Cesars-Computer: webapps] $ ls -la
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@  7 cbs_sp  admin   238 Oct  3 04:52 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 13 cbs_sp  admin   442 Nov  7 17:09 ..
drwxr-xr-x@  4 cbs_sp  admin   136 Nov 13 12:53 ROOT
drwxr-xr-x@ 52 cbs_sp  admin  1768 Oct  3 04:52 docs
drwxr-xr-x@  7 cbs_sp  admin   238 Oct  3 04:52 examples
drwxr-xr-x@  7 cbs_sp  admin   238 Oct  3 04:52 host-manager
drwxr-xr-x@  8 cbs_sp  admin   272 Oct  3 04:52 manager
[Cesars-Computer: webapps] $ cd ROOT
[Cesars-Computer: ROOT] $ ls -la
total 348080
drwxr-xr-x@ 4 cbs_sp  admin        136 Nov 13 12:53 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 cbs_sp  admin        238 Oct  3 04:52 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 cbs_sp  admin       6148 Nov 13 12:53 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--@ 1 cbs_sp  admin  178206477 Nov  7 14:46 liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558.war
```

Comment: What do you have deployed under TOMCAT_HOME/webapps ?  Is there any mention of Liferay in the catalina logs ?

Comment: No, there isn't. I only deployed the liferay .war file, under $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/ROOT directory, but there is no trace of it on logs.

Comment: Just to be clear, the WAR should be placed in the webapps subdir, not  webapps/ROOT.  If this is Linux, can you list the "ls" output in /webapps ?

Comment: Adi Dembak, thanks a lot for your help. I've complemented the previous information with the directory structure, feel free to require any additional information. So,... if I put the War into the webapps folder it will work, but not properly. When I run it from webapps directory directly, the css, and other files are not loaded, and the pages are not rendered as expected.

Comment: I've used Liferay on my machine with the bundled version and it works fine, at localhost root ('/'). But I want to deploy it to my VPS, and thats why I am trying to run the War version. The intention of the War file on ROOT folder is to run the Liferay at localhost root ('/'), and that's what I need. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

If anyone faced this same problem, just change the name of the .war to ROOT.war, and put it under webapps/ directory, it will work fine!

And If you are following the steps from Liferay site, as I did. At some point the tutorial will tell you to create a ROOT.xml, when you do that, just add the Context parent node, which, until the moment I wrote this, was not mentioned in the tutorial example's snippet.

**My ROOT.xml**:

```
[Cesars-Computer: apache-tomcat-7.0.32] $ cd conf/Catalina/localhost/
[Cesars-Computer: localhost] $ cat ROOT.xml 
<Context path="" crossContext="true">

</Context>
```

Thanks and success to everyone,